# Ajax request with authorization

Tags: jquery, ajax, bad-request

I try to make ajax request with autorization header:

[image]

but  get:  `GET http://agroagro.com/agroMobile/v1/tasks 400 (Bad Request)`

my ajax code:

```
$(function() { 

if (localStorage.getItem('apiKey') == '') {
window.location.replace("login.html");  
}
    else {  

var urlAjax = "http://agroagro.com/agroMobile/v1/tasks";

$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url: urlAjax,
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
headers: {
    "Authorization": localStorage.getItem('apiKey')
  },
beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('apiKey'));
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Authorization", localStorage.getItem('apiKey'));
},

  success: function(data) { 

    console.log('Lets do something');  


  },
error: function(data) {
    //window.location.replace("login.html");
    console.log(data); 
    console.log(console.log(localStorage.getItem('apiKey')));
  $('#error').append('<p>Please enter the correct information</p>');
    },
dataType: 'json',

});

    }

});
```

So why I get this error? As you can see I send right autorization api key and everything is fine but just dont work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By manually accessing the URL I can see you are missing an API key. You should be able to see the content of your request in the preview/response tabs of the console. That will likely give you a lot of information.

Have you read the API docs for the service you are connecting to?

Comment: the preview say: error: true
message: "Api key is misssing" , also I do exactly as need for connecting, I dont know why say api key is missing becouse I see there is api key

Comment: Where do you see the API key? I dont see it in the headers you show.

Comment: See on image: Authorization, thats api-key

Comment: do you have a link to the API documentation?

Comment: yes, http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/ that is API

Comment: Looks like a bug in the PHP code. Are you running the PHP side locally (where you can access it?) If so, try replacing the error message with `print_r($headers,true)' to see what the headers of the request are

Comment: {"error":true,"message":"Array\n(\n    [Content-Type] => application\/x-www-form-urlencoded\n    [Accept] => application\/json, text\/javascript, *\/*; q=0.01\n    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, sdch\n    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.8,sr;q=0.6,bg;q=0.4,hr;q=0.2\n    [Cache-Control] => max-age=0\n    [Connection] => close\n    [Cookie] => __cfduid=dd63d38a39a5055931cea185c8022e7371395071758399; __zlcprivacy=1; __zlcmid=RPe961HGLYe4TG; _ga=GA1.2.951152061.1416241480\n    [Host] => agroagro.com\n    [Referer] => http:\/\/agroagro.com\/agroMobile\/\n    [User-Agent] => Mozill ...

Comment: that I get now ... when I replace $response["message"] = print_r($headers,true);

Comment: What can be a problem? maybe hosting provider, server ?

Comment: maybe the problme can be  apache_request_headers and PHP versions ?

Comment: It looks like the problem is with your hosting provider. It looks like your request doesnt go directly to your server, but gets routed via a proxy. That proxy isnt forwarding your headers.

Comment: I see that  apache_request_headers() function dont exist in every PHP version

Comment: What can be replavment for that function?

Comment: you could put the authorization token as part of the query string, or use POST and put it as part of the POST data. The problem isnt apache_request_headers, its returning the headers. But the header you want isnt being forwarded. It also looks like it is only the `Authorization` header that is blocked, so you could try changing the code to expect a header called `Auth`